# Is Minecraft Bedrock Edition backwards compatible with minor versions?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, hosting, backwards-compatibility

For example, a client with version 1.17.1 tries to join a server running version 1.17.0 - does this work? What about the other way around?

Answer (score -1):

Seems so as long as they meet these requirments
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Protocol_version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).